# What happens if you are left behind on a mission in Warframe?

Tags: warframe

On Warframe, what happens if you are left behind during the extraction when the timer runs out? On a VOID KEY mission, all that happened was that I lost the money reward, but what happens on a normal mission? Is it the same, or do you not get anything at all and it is considered a mission fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the timer runs out before you get to extraction, you only lose the credit reward. All mods, resources, mission reward mods and items will be kept. The next mission is also unlocked.

(As of Update 9)

Comment: Consider adding to the answer: What about mods that are a reward for completing the mission (like with some Alert missions)? What about campaign map unlocks - will the next node(s) for the given planet be unlocked?

Comment: All of that is also rewarded, it is only credits that you might miss out on.